# Browser notifications not working in Firefox Add-on

Tags: notifications, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, bugzilla

I am using Windows 7 and developing a Firefox add-on that needs to display notifications, but none are being displayed.  I have confirmed that the command `browser.notifications.create` is being executed in the background script and the returned promise fulfilled with an ID.

I ran a regression on Firefox builds using Mozilla's mozregression tool along with their notifications example at https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/notify-link-clicks-i18n.  I found that the last known good build was on **2018-09-25**, and the next day's build was bad.  The tool gave me a response of "*Unable to find enough data to bisect*"

I searched Bugzilla but found nothing, which seemed strange since apparently this issue is over 2 years old.  So before I submit a bug report, does anyone have any ideas what the issue might be?

Edit: As requested, here's the code

```
browser.notifications.create({
    "type": "basic",
    "iconUrl": browser.extension.getURL("icons/link-48.png"),
    "title": title,
    "message": content
});
```

Comment: Probably need to post your code, notifications are still working for me.

Comment: @PaulHeil
The code is at the GitHub link I posted in the question.